# Why does Mathematica not apply Together to this (purely numeric) expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, numerics

At the end of some computation I arrive at a lengthy but purely numerical expression involving roots. I wonder why Mathematica left me with this result (I manually indented it such that opening and associated closing parentheses vertically match to make the structure for a human reader more easy to recognize):

```
expr = (2/Sqrt[33] - 
        (Sqrt[2/165] + Sqrt[6/55])/Sqrt[10]
       )/Sqrt[25/33 + 
              (2/Sqrt[33] - 
               (3*(Sqrt[2/165] + Sqrt[6/55]))/Sqrt[10]
              )^2 + 
              (2/Sqrt[33] - 
               (Sqrt[2/165] + Sqrt[6/55])/Sqrt[10]
              )^2
             ] == 
       6/Sqrt[665]                                            (* 1 *)
```

If I take the lhs of this expression, Mathematica still leaves me with it after I copy it and paste it to a new expression which I execute then:

```
lhs = (2/Sqrt[33] - 
       (Sqrt[2/165] + Sqrt[6/55])/Sqrt[10]
      )/Sqrt[25/33 + 
             (2/Sqrt[33] - 
              (3*(Sqrt[2/165] + Sqrt[6/55]))/Sqrt[10]
             )^2 + 
             (2/Sqrt[33] - 
              (Sqrt[2/165] + Sqrt[6/55])/Sqrt[10]
             )^2
            ]                                                 (* 2 *)
```

This expression remains unchanged (except for format change).

However, if I expressively apply `Together` or `Simplify` to lhs the result is

> `6/Sqrt[665]`

which of course should have resulted in True for (* 1 *) if it would have been computed there.

If Mathematica would have applied the rule

```
Equal[a_, b_] :> Equal[Simplify[a], Simplify[b]]`
```

to (* 1 *) it would have resulted in `True`:

```
expr /. Equal[a_, b_] :> Equal[Simplify[a], Simplify[b]]      (* 3 *)
```

yields `True`. Of course, a delayed rule ( :> ) has to be applied here instead of a normal one ( -> ).

If I replace the equal sign in `expr` by a subtraction, it still leaves me with a lengthy *purely numerical result* which easily could be reduced from leaf count of 111 by simply applying `Together` to 0, a result with a leaf count of 1.

#### Questions

Why does Mathematica not try `Together` to simplify this purely numerical result?

How can one "teach" Mathematica to apply `Together` to large purely numerical sub-expressions like the ones discussed in this post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can one "teach" *Mathematica* to try `Together` on the lhs and on the rhs of an equation separately if it was not able to decide it before doing so?

You could use the built-in global variable [`$Post`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Post.html) to this end.

The following definition tries reformulating the left-hand side `lhs` and right-hand side `rhs` of an output expression of the form `lhs == rhs`. The way both sides of the equation are reexpressed is given by the symbols `lhsTransform` and `rhsTransform`, the definitions of which are given separately.

```
$Post = Module[{expr = #, lhs, rhs},
          If[Head[expr] === Equal,
              lhs = First@ expr;
              rhs = Last@ expr;
              lhsTransform[lhs] == rhsTransform[rhs],
              expr
          ]
]&;
```

For your specific question, the post-processing could be called with the transformation functions:

```
lhsTransform[lhs_] := Together[lhs];
rhsTransform[rhs_] := Together[rhs];
```

which gives the expected result:

```
(2/Sqrt[33] - (Sqrt[2/165] + Sqrt[6/55])/Sqrt[10]) / 
Sqrt[25/33 + (2/Sqrt[33] - (3*(Sqrt[2/165] + Sqrt[6/55]) ) / Sqrt[10])^2 
           + (2/Sqrt[33] - (Sqrt[2/165] + Sqrt[6/55]) / Sqrt[10])^2
] == 6/Sqrt[665]

(* True *)
```

Note that the definitions of `lhsTransform` and `rhsTransform` are minimal, they do not check whether a given side is `NumericQ`. They will apply accordingly the symbol `Together` for non purely numeric arguments as well.

To get this restriction, the definitions could be refined as

```
lhsTransform[lhs : Except[_Integer | _Rational | _Real | _Complex, _?NumericQ]] := 
    Together[lhs];
lhsTransform[lhs_] := lhs;
rhsTransform[rhs : Except[_Integer | _Rational | _Real | _Complex, _?NumericQ]] := 
    Together[rhs];
rhsTransform[rhs_] := rhs;
```

The exceptions on the heads of `lhs` and `rhs` avoid `Together` to be applied on numeric quantities that would remain unchanged.

Comment: Yes, \$Post = Simplify  or  \$PrePrint = Simplify did solve my problem, even those problems which I added in my edidet post. Xavier goes one step further how to restrict Simplify to expressions lhs==rhs.